# Android Mp3 live streaming from url

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hello everyone,
                I'm trying to play mp3 audio from a url (radio) using media player class. It is running but it took too much time to start. I know this question is already asked on this site. But I need help. If their is no solution for that kindly tell me alternative method . Reference code or tutorial would be a great help.here is my java code.

```
  public void streaming(String url)
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        Log.i("stream", "connecting data source");
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        Log.i("stream", "preparing");
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        Log.i("stream", "prepared");
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Log.i("stream", "Started");

}


}
```